# Help determining whether this series converges or diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I would like to determine whether $\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(4n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(4n+3)^2}-\frac{1}{2n+2}$ converges or diverges. Can anyone give me an idea on how to accomplish this? Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you sum each term separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't, because $ \Sigma (\frac{1}{(4n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(4n+3)^2}) $ converges and $\sum\frac{1}{2n+2} $ doens't.

So if $\Sigma (\frac{1}{(4n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(4n+3)^2}-\frac{1}{2n+2})$ converges then $\Sigma (\frac{1}{(4n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(4n+3)^2} -(\frac{1}{(4n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(4n+3)^2}-\frac{1}{2n+2}))=\sum \frac{1}{2n+2} $ does as well, which is absurd.

Answer (score 0):

The series has three different terms.
The third term (1/(2n+2)) fails to converge by the integral test (many ways to do this).

Independent of the first two terms, the series diverges because sums containing infinity are indeterminate.

Comment: The series $\sum(\frac{n+1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n})$ converges, even though the last term gives a divergent series.

Comment: I should have said,"since the first two terms yield convergent sums and the last term yields a divergent sum, the series diverges."

Comment: Right; you can edit your answer to say this if you want to.

Comment: You already know what to do though.  Why?  Does it matter?  Thank you

Comment: No, that's fine if you don't want to do this - I only meant this as a suggestion.

Comment: I don't know the correct protocol so thank you